# Debug compiled Java .class files in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm taking a CS Data Structures course, and I want to try and work with VS Code instead of the current editor that I'm using (BlueJ). However, my work is evaluated based on whether it can satisfy a certain set of tests presented by a **compiled** tester file (a `.class` file that I can use to run/check my work), something that VS Code doesn't seem to particularly like.

This tester is what contains the program's `main()` method, so I either need to use BlueJ (which already supports running compiled classes) or run the file from the command line (something that I know how to do, but have found somewhat tedious) in order to run the method. Is there a way that I could configure a VS Code Java debugger to execute the `main()` method located within my compiled tester file?

**A note:** These tester files do not come with editable `.java` counterparts; if we were able to see what the tester checks for, that would ruin the point of the tester!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, But:
For tedious commands, you could set up an alias in your `$HOME/.bash_aliases` file.
[Bash Aliases](https://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) .

i.e one i aliased earlier :

`alias ds="java -cp $HOME/javaWorkScripts/jspDatabaseApp/bin/ FormatTabContents $HOME/VSCODE\ Research/SURFACE-TIDE-JSP-DATABASE-APP-22-DEC-2018.txt "`

From now on, you could just type `ds` in terminal to run the command.

Comment: If it's bash you could just write a script to do it, that accepts input variables. just make your script say `java -cp $HOME/javaWorkScripts/jspDatabaseApp/bin/ FormatTabContents $HOME/VSCODE\ Research/$1` and the $1 variable will pass in the first argument to the script for a file name.

Comment: @RobertCotterman Yeah, i see. Your option would be more efficient since it could be used for other "input variables".

Answer (score -1):

You can decompile and debug the class in IntelliJ easily. Then set break points on main method and check it.
You can decompile the class in VS code easily but I doubt you will be able to debug the .class file in VS Code.